# Scilab compatibility with Mac OS Monterey

Tags: macos, scilab, macos-monterey

I am successfully running Scilab 6.1 on Mac Os Catalina.  According to the excellent webpage

[https://www.utc.fr/~mottelet/scilab_for_macOS.html](https://www.utc.fr/%7Emottelet/scilab_for_macOS.html)

6.1.1 runs on Mac OS Big Sur

However, I can find no mentions on that page (or scouring the internet) whether 6.1.1 runs on Mac OS Monterey.  Before upgrading from Catalina, I need to know this.

Can anyone confirm successful operation of 6.1.1 on Monterey?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reported that the macOS M1 build works on Monterey. Likely, the Intel build should also work, even if you may have a warning at launch (concerning the OS version).

Comment: Thank you very much, Stephane.  I hope to migrate in the next couple of weeks and will report my experience.

Comment: I just tested this afternoon both builds: you just have to click "try anyway" and Scilab runs fine.